# How to calculate for each month the overall value of a portfolio given each month I invested a different amount?

Tags: python

I have a dataset like this:

```
df.head(10)
              Adj Close   macd     signal         hist  investment  current_price   returns
Date                            
2010-06-01  75.489998   0.382352    0.022635    0.359717    5000    392.32  25984.899397
2010-07-01  69.430000   0.983398    0.383040    0.600357    0       392.32  0.000000
2010-08-02  73.230003   -0.227501   0.276055    -0.503556   5000    392.32  26786.834768
2010-09-01  71.739998   -0.804435   -0.002094   -0.802340   5000    392.32  27343.184533
2010-10-01  71.370003   -0.340653   -0.138923   -0.201731   10000   392.32  54969.873182
2010-11-01  73.040001   -0.454064   -0.273669   -0.180395   15000   392.32  80569.549921
2010-12-01  78.309998   1.038864    -0.086955   1.125819    5000    392.32  25049.164362
2011-01-03  81.720001   3.581994    0.792240    2.789753    0       392.32  0.000000
2011-02-01  80.820000   4.674431    2.074357    2.600074    0       392.32  0.000000
```

where Adj Close is the price of a stock at that date, in the investment column I put how much I want to invest that month.
How can I compute for each month the overall value of my portfolio?

Comment: I would keep a count of how many stocks you have, then each time you invest, you calculate how many stocks you are buying. this means that to calculate your value, you just multiply the number of stocks by `adj close` for that month

Comment: but I do think that [money stack exchange](https://money.stackexchange.com) is probably a better bet than here

Answer (score 0):

You can have a column representing your rolling stocks and the overall value will just be the price * rolling_total_stocks until that date.

```
df['total_stocks'] = df["investment"]/df['Adj Close']
df['portfolio_value'] = df['total_stocks'].cumsum() * df['Adj Close']
```

Comment: How is multiplying investment (in dollars) by price (in dollars) going to give you the value? This is incorrect.

Comment: I assumed 'investment' was the number of stocks invested, not the total price. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a count of the total number of stocks you own and multiply this by "Adj Close" to get the value of your portfolio:

```
df["Value"] = df["investment"].div(df["Adj Close"]).cumsum().mul(df["Adj Close"])

>>> df
         Date  Adj Close      macd  ...  current_price       returns         Value
0  2010-06-01  75.489998  0.382352  ...         392.32  25984.899397   5000.000000
1  2010-07-01  69.430000  0.983398  ...         392.32      0.000000   4598.622456
2  2010-08-02  73.230003 -0.227501  ...         392.32  26786.834768   9850.311627
3  2010-09-01  71.739998 -0.804435  ...         392.32  27343.184533  14649.888126
4  2010-10-01  71.370003 -0.340653  ...         392.32  54969.873182  24574.332153
5  2010-11-01  73.040001 -0.454064  ...         392.32  80569.549921  40149.350842
6  2010-12-01  78.309998  1.038864  ...         392.32  25049.164362  48046.214965
7  2011-01-03  81.720001  3.581994  ...         392.32      0.000000  50138.383799
8  2011-02-01  80.820000  4.674431  ...         392.32      0.000000  49586.198348

[9 rows x 9 columns]
```